# How to subscribe to event of Attached property inside custom control in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I'm working on custom control that I can use for interactions within my app UI. So, my idea is that control will bind to `IInteractionsProvider` which has it's events. And then, I will call method on this provider that will raise event to my control to do what it needs to do.

Problem is, I have no idea how to properly subscribe to event `InteractionRequired` inside my custom control.

Basically, I don't know how to properly hook and unhook event and at what time inside control.

```
public interface IInteractionsProvider
    {
        event EventHandler InteractionRequested;

        void RequestInteraction(Action<object> callback);
    } 



public class MyInteractions : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContainerProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Container", typeof(Grid), typeof(IdattInteractions), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InteractionsProviderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InteractionsProvider", typeof(IInteractionsProvider), typeof(IdattInteractions), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public IdattInteractions()
        {
            DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyInteractions);
        }

        public Grid Container
        {
            get { return GetValue(ContainerProperty) as Grid; }
            set { this.SetValue(ContainerProperty, value); }
        }

        public IInteractionsProvider InteractionsProvider
        {
            get { return (IInteractionsProvider)GetValue(InteractionsProviderProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(InteractionsProviderProperty, value); }
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool) return;

            if (this.InteractionsProvider == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("InteractionsProvider wasn't specified. If you don't need interactions on this view - please remove MyInteractions from XAML");
            }

            if (this.Container != null)
            {
                if (this.Container.GetType() != typeof(Grid))
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Specified container must be of Grid type");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.Container = TreeHelper.FindParentGridByName(this, "LayoutRoot") ?? TreeHelper.FindParent<Grid>(this);

                if (this.Container == null)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Container wasn't specified and parent Grid wasn't found");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To attach to events on a dependency property (or to do anything with a dependency property when its assigned) you can use the callback delegate on the `PropertyMetadata`.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InteractionsProviderProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("InteractionsProvider", typeof(IInteractionsProvider), typeof(IdattInteractions), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnInteractionsProviderPropertyChanged)); 

    private static void OnInteractionsProviderPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

         var source = d As MyInteractions;
         if (source ! = null)
         {
             var oldValue = (IInteractionsProvider)e.OldValue;
             var newValue = (IInteractionsProvider)e.NewValue;
             source.OnInteractionsProviderPropertyChanged(oldValue, newValue);
         }
    }
    private void OnInteractionsProviderPropertyChanged(IInteractionsProvider oldValue, IInteractionsProvider newValue)
    {
         if (oldValue != null)
              oldValue -= InteractionsProvider_InteractionRequested;

         if (newValue != null)
              newValue += InteractionsProvider_InteractionRequested;
    }
    private void InteractionsProvider_InteractionRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
```

Comment: What about way phoog suggested? I like that approach better, not sure if there any concerns about it?

Comment: @katit: See my comment on that answer

Comment: Thanks! I guess his newValue should be value. And I guess in dependency property declaration in your example it should be OnInteractionsProviderPropertyChanged not OnInteractionsProviderProperty, right?

Comment: @katit: nope in this case newValue is newValue.  The call back delegate assignment was incorrect it should be `OnInteractionsProviderPropertyChanged`, I have corrected.

Comment: @katit in my answer, yes, newValue should be value.  I corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public IInteractionsProvider InteractionsProvider 
{ 
    get { return (IInteractionsProvider)GetValue(InteractionsProviderProperty); } 
    set {
        var oldValue = this.InteractionsProvider;
        if (oldValue != null)
            oldValue.InteractionRequested -= this.HandleInteractionRequested;
        if (value != null)
            value.InteractionRequested += this.HandleInteractionRequested;
        this.SetValue(InteractionsProviderProperty, value);
    } 
} 

private void HandleInteractionRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: When working with dependency properties alway use the property changed callback.  The standard .NET property setter method isn't always called when the property is assigned.  For example if binding is used to assign it Silverlight calls `SetValue` directly, it won't call the setter code you have included in your answer.  BTW, where does newValue come from?

Comment: ^^^ What he said.  The XAML parser completely bypasses your property get/set definition.  It is there for programmer convenience, nothing more.  You should never put any code other than a call to GetValue or SetValue in there because the binding system bypasses that code.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones thanks for the tip.  `newValue` was supposed to be `value`; I corrected that.